# Parametrs of the Uniform Likelihood

Tags: time-series, estimation, linear-model

Consider linear scalar model $y_k = x_k + w_k$ where $w_k \sim U(a,b)$.

What we can say about the probability distribution $p(y_k|x_k)$?

We can show that $p(y_k|x_k)$ have uniform density, but I caanot determine the parameters of this density.

$$\begin{array}{l}
{p_{{Y_k}|{X_k}}}\left( {{y_k}|{x_k}} \right) = \frac{{{p_{{X_k},{Y_k}}}({x_k},{y_k})}}{{{p_{{X_k}}}({x_k})}} = \frac{{{p_{{W_k},{X_k}}}({y_k} - {x_k},{x_k})}}{{{p_{{X_k}}}({x_k})}} = \frac{{{p_{{X_k}}}({x_k}) \times {p_W}({y_k} - {x_k})}}{{{p_{{X_k}}}({x_k})}} = {p_W}({y_k} - {x_k})\\
{p_W}({w_k})\sim U(a,b) \Rightarrow {p_W}({y_k} - {x_k})\sim U(???)
\end{array}$$

**Edit:**

Please pay attention what we know about $x_k$ is the density $p(x_{k}|y_{1:k−1}) \sim \mathcal{N}(x_{k}; 2, 4)$; but as we are conditioning on $x_k $, it now is a fixed value.

Comment: This is a question about addition: when you add the constant $x_k$ to the range of values from $-2$ to $2,$ what range results?

Comment: If x=2, it is just 0 and 4! So, the likelihood becomes $U(a+x_k, b+x_k)$?

Comment: Why the exclamation point?  Are the facts that 2+-2=0 and 2+2=4 in this context a surprise?  In what way?  (I'm trying to figure out what you might be looking for in terms of an answer to your original question.)

Comment: @whuber I think it should be $p(y_k|x_k) \sim \mathcal{U}(-4, +4)$; but I do not know how to reach this!

Comment: Please pay attention what we know about $x_k$ is the density $p(x_{k}|y_{1:k−1}) = \mathcal{N}(x_{k}; 2, 4)$; but as we are conditioning on $x_k $, it now is a fixed value. @whuber

Comment: I'll leave it to you to determine whether the value of 2 + -2 is -4 or 0.

Comment: @whuber +1 :-D. So, in general the density becomes  $U(a+x_k,b+x_k)$, Ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93928/discussion-between-sci9-and-whuber).